# Merging MongoDB Tags

Tags: support, retag-request

The below two sets of tags can potentially can be merged.

Most of the questions tagged under [mongo-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-java) are not tagged under [mongdb-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongdb-java).

- [mongo-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-java) has 254 questions.
- [mongodb-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-java) has 818 questions.

The wiki for each of them leads to the same information and setup.

Most of the questions tagged under [mongoid4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoid4) or [mongoid3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoid3) are tagged under [mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoid).

- [mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoid) has 3533 questions.
- [mongoid4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoid4) has 58 questions.
- [mongoid3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoid3) has 211 questions.

So is a merge possible for both these cases?

Comment: First one looks like a YES.  The second one is a big NO.  Those are version specific tags and should remain.  Though technically they should be formatted with a dash between.

Comment: Was there any closure on the first merge request in this post? I second that as well. Infact I believe that the [tag:mongo-java-driver] can also be merged into one.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307724/mongodb-3-and-mongodb-2-should-have-different-tags