# mongodb-3 and mongodb-2 should have different tags

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

Please anyone with reputation (1500) higher then mine create different tags for mongodb-2 and mongodb-3, cos differences are huge. Much not supported in 2, now is supported. And some is obsolete. And mongo is developed fast... Answers sometimes are opposite for 2 and 3 releases. like this one: [Can you have collection level permissions in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883649/can-you-have-collection-level-permissions-in-mongodb) says no (and it was true before 2.6), and in later releases it is yes http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/

I believe there should be mongodb-2.6 mongodb-3 and mongodb-pre-2.6